# Typing of Pali Language in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, language-support

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and I need to type Pali (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pali). Has anyone some suggestions how I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Enable iBus**

   - From Menu, System -> Administration -> Language Support
   - Under "Keyboard input method system" choose ibus
2. **Create a new input method file for transliteration**

   ```
   gksudo gedit /usr/share/m17n/sa-translit.mim
   ```

   The following is the complete content of the file which can be easily copied and pasted and changed according to your taste. Save it, before closing the file:

   ```
   ;;; sa-translit.mim
   ;;;
   ;;; Input method for Sanskrit transliteration using the ITRANS scheme.

   (input-method t sa-translit)

   (title "sa-translit")

   (map
   (trans

   ("aa" "ā")
   ("AA" "Ā")
   ("ii" "ī")
   ("II" "Ī")
   ("uu" "ū")
   ("UU" "Ū")
   (".r" "ṛ")
   (".R" "Ṛ")
   (".rr" "ṝ")
   (".RR" "Ṝ")
   (".l" "ḷ")
   (".L" "Ḷ")
   (".ll" "ḹ")
   (".LL" "Ḹ")
   (".M" "ṁ")
   (".m" "ṃ")
   (".h" "ḥ")
   (".H" "Ḥ")
   (";n" "ṅ")
   (";N" "Ṅ")
   ("~n" "ñ")
   ("~N" "Ñ")
   (".t" "ṭ")
   (".T" "Ṭ")
   (".d" "ḍ")
   (".D" "Ḍ")
   (".n" "ṇ")
   (".N" "Ṇ")
   (";s" "ś")
   (";S" "Ś")
   (".s" "ṣ")
   (".S" "Ṣ")
   ))

   (state
   (init
   (trans)))
   ```
3. **Add Sa-translit to IBus**

   From menu, System -> Preferences -> IBus Preferences -> add input method: under the "Other" category, choose "sa-translit".
4. **Typing Pali**

   If you want to type in Pali switch to "sa-translit" (keyboard sign) and use the following key combinations:

   ```
   ITRANS Method

   aa = ā
   AA = Ā
   ii = ī
   II = Ī
   uu = ū
   UU = Ū
   .r = ṛ
   .R = Ṛ
   .rr = ṝ
   .RR = Ṝ
   .l = ḷ
   .L = Ḷ
   .ll = ḹ
   .LL = Ḹ
   .M = ṁ
   .m = ṃ
   .h = ḥ
   .H = Ḥ
   ;n = ṅ
   ;N = Ṅ
   ~n = ñ
   ~N = Ñ
   .t = ṭ
   .T = Ṭ
   .d = ḍ
   .D = Ḍ
   .n = ṇ
   .N = Ṇ
   ;s = ś
   ;S = Ś
   .s = ṣ
   .S = Ṣ
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this but did not work.

Best option is to create macros in LibreWriter for each Pali letter.
Remember to enable macro recording. Click on Tools, Options, LibreOffice, Advanced - for enabling macro recording.
Then open LibreWriter and start recording macro for each Pali diacritical letter (You can find 'record macro' in the drop-down menu of 'Tools').
Once it is done, set the keys for each macro (i.e. each diacritical letter) using 'Customise' in Tools.

If recording macros is new to you, then please consult the LibreOffice documentation and similar sources.

Similar macro setting for diacritical letters
can be done with OpenOffice also.

As a side note: In Windows10, if you choose English(IN) as input language in "keyboard", you can click on 'altgr' and easily type all the Pali diacritical letters. But the same layout for English(IN) is not available in Linux systems.